# How do I register HTTP client in Blazor .NET 8?

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

I am used to registering the httpclient in the program.cs of the client project as follows

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("My.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

However this does not work in Blazor .net8. I get errors saying that there is

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'Http'
> on type 'My.Client.Pages.RiskReview'. There is no
> registered service of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.

What do I need to do to register the httpclient in blazor .net 8?

I am using webassembly rendering

Comment: Can you post the class that is generating the error? The one where the HttpClient is being injected.

Comment: Did you end up solving the issue? Neither of the provided answers nor [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=webassembly#package](Microsoft's page) is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I did it with .NET 8:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(http => new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
}) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

My error was a bit different, but installing `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` NuGet package made `.AddHttpClient` extension available in the client project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `HttpClient` to the service collection to be able to inject it.

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddHttpClient("My.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

// add this
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("My.ServerAPI"));
```

If you just call `AddHttpClient` you are only able to inject the `IHttpClientFactory` and then you have to use `using HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("My.ServerAPI");` to get the `HttpClient`.

Comment: Does not work for me.